# Download remote server xml to local(only update is available)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an XML file that is going to live on our server. The first time I request an url   and  download it locally for use within my app. it's working.if the download is available   only means we are again go to url and download.
, I compare the local time stamp to the remote file time stamp and only re-download it if   the time stamp is newer (e.g. it has been updated).

I am using http post method.If the download is  not available i can cancel      connection.else..download the server data and update the last modified date to local xml.

**Is   it correct or any other better way to check**

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)])   {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];

```
      BOOL check=[self checkUpdate:[[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"]];  

    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary description]);
    if (!check) {

    [connection cancel];
        [delegate display];
    }

}
```

-(BOOL) checkUpdate:(NSString*) str
{
    self.lastmodified=str;
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 //
    self.cachedPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",docDir,self.refxml];

```
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];    

lastModifiedServer = [[NSDate date] retain];  
@try {    
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
    df.dateFormat = @"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'";    
    df.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];    
    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];    
    [lastModifiedServer release];  
         lastModifiedServer = [[df dateFromString: self.lastmodified]retain];    
    [df release];    
}    
@catch (NSException * e) {    
    NSLog(@"Error parsing last modified date: %@ - %@",  self.lastmodified, [e   description]);    
}   
NSDate *lastModifiedLocal = nil;   
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.cachedPath]) {    
    NSError *error = nil;    
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:cachedPath error:&error];   
       lastModifiedLocal = [fileAttributes fileModificationDate];  
    if ([lastModifiedLocal laterDate:lastModifiedServer] == lastModifiedServer) {    
        return  YES;      
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return NO;  
    }  
} 
else  
{   
    return YES;  
}  

    return YES;
```

}